# nginx detecting sudden disconnect of client

Tags: sockets, nginx, keep-alive

At this point we are using long poll with keepalives on the tcp level.
If we pull the eth cable out of the client, client does not detect a dead connection until the keepalive counters finish what they are supposed to do.

But what happens on the nginx level ? When and how will nginx detect the same dead connection? How long will the connection be open from the nginx side ?

Should we use keepalive from nginx to client as well ?

Thank you!